# Anesthetics during Brit milah

Tags: halacha, brit-milah, parashat-lech-lecha, contemporary-halacha, responsa

Is it permissible to use Anesthetics (for the purpose of pain relief) during circumcision (Brit milah)? I would imagine it would not be problematic per se, but perhaps being conscious is preferable during circumcision. There’s also the consideration of not harming another living being.

Comment: https://www.etzion.org.il/en/halakha/yoreh-deah/circumcision/use-anesthesia-during-circumcision

Comment: related: [Anesthesia for a Bris](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77868/11501)

Answer (score 1):

Rav Moshe Feinstein rules that it is permitted. (However, I heard from an anesthesiologist that for babies there is no point, as the injection would be equally painful to the bris itself.)

Comment: One mohel told me he found the topical anesthetic made the skin slipperier and thus harder for him to work with. Again, practical concerns.